# CloverETL Versioning Server projects

Tags: svn, subclipse, cloveretl

Does anyone know how to version server projects in CloverEtl, 
I've tried using subclipse and SVN. That has work for local projects. But the server sandboxes I can not. It says the project is not locally stored or in workspace but they should be locally stored as i am working on the server.

Any help at all with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from CloverETL development team - we are currently updating the server projects to support using versioning tools directly with the projects. You will be able to use Eclipse versioning plugins or even versioning tools outside of Eclipse.

Comment: Any Idea when this will be available

Comment: I heard late summer, but milestone preview to experiment with should be soonish.

Comment: We've just released 4.2.0-M1, which is a milestone preview release available for you to download: http://www.cloveretl.com/content/cloveretl-42-milestone-released

Comment: That looks like exactly what i need. Thanks

Comment: Production version should be out now too.

Answer (score 0):

We create a deployment package that is a bundle of CloverETL graph & job files. We keep parameters separate. Its not just the cloverETL code that needs to be versioned, its also the accompanying DDL's and application code that needs to be packaged together.

Answer (score 0):

we have good experience with possibility of downloading sandbox as a zip file directly from server web gui, unzipping this archive and store it in SVN.

Releases are similiar - extract sandbox from SVN, zip it and upload to the server by web gui.

Another way can is to have SVN checkout on your server in the folder with sandboxes. It can be easy way how to handle this, but your server needs connection to the SVN repository.

If my information is correct there will be improvements of working with versioning systems in the upcoming releases of CloverETL.

Hope this helps